# Unity -Facebook SDK - Error building Player: Win32Exception

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

After installing the Facebook SDK to my project I get this error trying to build my game (android device):

Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='javac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath "D:/Documents/androidSDK/platforms/android-22\android.jar" -d "D:\Documents\multec\3D real time\Pinball2\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com\facebook\android\R.java" "com\StarWardo\Pinball\R.java"', CurrentDirectory='D:\Documents\multec\3D real time\Pinball2\Temp\StagingArea\gen'

Answer (score 0):

I installed the java jdk 32 and it fixed my error.